# Bash: more than one arguments for each flag

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, getopts

What I want to do is something like

```
$ ./my-script -a file1 file2 file3 -d file4 file5 file6 -r file7 file8
```

or

```
$ ./my-script -a *.txt -d src1/*.tex sr2/*.tex
```

However, it seems getopts only support zero or one argument per flag.

Is there a good way to handle this requirement? I'm currently parsing the argument by myself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a single comma-delimited (or some other delimter) argument for each option:

```
$ ./my-script -a file1,file2,file3 -d file4,file5,file6 -r file7,file8
```

Then split the individual arguments after you parse the options. One way to do that:

```
IFS=, read a1 a2 a3 <<< $a_argument
```

or

```
IFS=, read -a a <<< $a_argument
```

---

Another option is to quote the argument, and let the script do the expansion:

```
./my-script -a '*.tex' -d '*.pdf'
$ ./my-script -a '*.txt' -d 'src1/*.tex sr2/*.tex'
```

where in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

as=( $a_argument )
ds=( $d_argument )
```

This is similar to how `find` handles, e.g, the `-name` primary.

Comment: I would like to use the script like this: ./my-script -a *.tex -d *.pdf, which it is not convenient to add delimters like you suggested..

Comment: You could let wildcards expand in the script instead of that happening on the command line.

Comment: @William, you may be viewing a stale cached copy of my answer; that's what I recommended earlier.

Comment: That appears to have been the case.